# Passing Values through Angular Adalauthenticationservice login

Tags: azure, authentication, adal, adal.js

I am creating angular application which involves authentication of user in AzureAD. So I am using ADALJs for authenticating user in AAD.Its working perfectly.

But I want to get some additional information about the user the before moving to adalauthenticationservice.login().Is there any way available to pass the values and get back in redirected URL in adalauthenticationservice.Login().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not clear on the question. You want to get some information about the user before the login has begun? Or you want to pass some information in the login url and get that back in the response?

Comment: I want to pass some information to redirecteduri...